# Dynamically display page list as one line on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

I have a list of anchor elements (it's a page navigator at the bottom of the page). On mobile, the list wraps to two lines. I want to keep it at one line for easier mobile use, and display only the page numbers that will fit within the screen. I don't want to do `whitespace: nowrap;` or `overflow-x: scroll` -- I want to have as many elements as possible display on one line without scrolling or disappearing into the horizontal ether.

I was thinking I'd determine the window width with jQuery, and if the width of the list as a whole exceeds the width of the screen, show only the elements on either side of the active page div that will fit on one line. Is there such a thing as "select certain number of siblings"?

I know .siblings() exists in jQuery as well as the CSS sibling selector, but these either select all siblings or only the one immediately adjacent sibling. I want to dynamically select the siblings on either side of the active element (page) depending on screen size.

Comment: I would just select all siblings, and then move back/forth one by one by accessing them via index.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, it's hard to tell exactly what you're doing. But I would use `whitespace: nowrap;` so that the elements are as wide as they can be, then you can loop through them and compare their width to the viewport or container width, and selectively hide them. (or alternatively, hide them by default with `opacity: 0;` or `visibility: hidden;` and only show the ones whose widths are less than the container/viewport). Something like this:

```
var cw = $('.container').width();
$('footer li').each(function() {
  if ($(this).width() > cw) {
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of each element to window width/number of items

```
var numberOfAnchors=$("a").length;
$("a").css("width",$(window).width()/numberOfAnchors+"px");
```

but make sure that the anchor display is different to `display:inline`